# Does Bob have to file a courtesy physical copy of his complaint to the courtroom clerk even if he e-files a suit?

Tags: california, civil-procedure, rules-of-court, process, electronic-procedure

For example, [Alameda County Superior Court Local Rule](http://www.alameda.courts.ca.gov/Resources/Documents/e-filing%20Technical%20Requirements.pdf) 3.30(c) provides as well as its "Technical E-Filing Requirements" instructs in point 12. "Printed Courtesy Copies" that

> "an identical[, printed] courtesy copy of any paper filed, lodged, or otherwise submitted in support of, in opposition to, or in connection with any motion or application must be delivered to the courtroom clerk assigned to the Department in which the motion or application will be heard[; f]or regular motions, such delivery must be made by noon the court day after the paper is filed, lodged or otherwise submitted".

**Do these regulations include the original complaint e-filed, too? In other words, does Bob have to file a physical copy with the courtroom clerk?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it says "any e-filed document submitted in support of, in opposition to,
or in connection with **any motion or application** must be delivered to the
courtroom clerk assigned to the Department in which the motion or application
will be heard" this appears to apply to motions and other requests and not to complaints.

This said, the easiest way to determine the answer would be to call the clerk of the court's office and ask. An answer from a clerk of the court would be definitive and easy to secure.